# Listview error can't run; force close

Tags: android, xml, database, listview

I've managed to show existing user in a textview. But it can only show one at a time so I decided to use listview.

```
package log1.log2;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AdminMain extends ListActivity {

 DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

      db = new DBAdapter(this);
   db.open();

   Cursor c = db.getAllUser(); 

   while (c.moveToNext()){

    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
      R.layout.adminmain, c, 
      new String[] { "Username" }, 
      new int[] {R.id.txtUser}));

   }

   db.close(); 
 }
}
```

But I received this error message from the logcat.

```
08-19 04:22:49.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{log1.log2/log1.log2.AdminMain}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I have added listview in listview.xml. I do not understand why the error msg tells me that.

I hope to receive helpful replies soon! Thank you very much!

-Dayne

---

## Edited

Hello again

For my xml, I got two xml file to make the listview work. First is `listview.xml` and second is `adminmain.xml`. For `listview.xml`, i've placed ***only listview***. And for `adminmain.xml`, I placed ***textview***.

`listview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

`adminmain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/image"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:text="USERNAMES HERE" 
    android:layout_x="100px"
    android:layout_y="102px"/>


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I've tried swapping the `R.layout`. The same error message appears.

I hope somebody can give me a good tip soon. Thank you for reading my post.

-Dayne

---

### After Editing

Here's the message from the log cat:

```
08-20 04:06:45.326: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Start proc log1.log2 for activity log1.log2/.AdminMain: pid=761 uid=10022 gids={}
08-20 04:06:45.456: DEBUG/dalvikvm(753): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 637060 of 4194304 (15%)
08-20 04:06:49.026: DEBUG/dalvikvm(761): GC freed 3633 objects / 145376 bytes in 166ms
08-20 04:06:51.876: WARN/System.err(658): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:51.886: WARN/System.err(658): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:51.895: INFO/jdwp(676): received file descriptor 27 from ADB
08-20 04:06:51.926: INFO/jdwp(687): received file descriptor 27 from ADB
08-20 04:06:55.227: WARN/ActivityManager(587): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-20 04:06:55.757: WARN/ActivityManager(587): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4367c578 {log1.log2/log1.log2.AdminMain}}
08-20 04:06:56.206: DEBUG/dalvikvm(761): GC freed 3325 objects / 126264 bytes in 142ms
08-20 04:06:56.927: WARN/System.err(687): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:56.927: WARN/System.err(687): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:56.957: WARN/System.err(676): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:56.957: WARN/System.err(676): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:56.967: INFO/jdwp(692): received file descriptor 33 from ADB
08-20 04:06:57.026: INFO/jdwp(707): received file descriptor 25 from ADB
08-20 04:06:57.066: WARN/System.err(692): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:06:57.066: WARN/System.err(692): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:07:04.906: WARN/System.err(707): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:07:04.936: WARN/System.err(707): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:07:04.957: INFO/jdwp(761): received file descriptor 26 from ADB
08-20 04:07:05.546: DEBUG/dalvikvm(658): GC freed 2935 objects / 166312 bytes in 264ms
08-20 04:07:09.946: DEBUG/dalvikvm(761): GC freed 3289 objects / 117368 bytes in 170ms
08-20 04:07:10.607: DEBUG/dalvikvm(692): GC freed 3379 objects / 202040 bytes in 326ms
08-20 04:07:15.486: DEBUG/dalvikvm(633): GC freed 2236 objects / 120792 bytes in 205ms
08-20 04:07:16.897: WARN/System.err(761): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
08-20 04:07:16.897: WARN/System.err(761): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
08-20 04:07:30.386: DEBUG/dalvikvm(761): GC freed 4161 objects / 124992 bytes in 184ms
08-20 04:07:35.147: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-20 04:07:35.246: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-20 04:07:35.346: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-20 04:07:35.466: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
08-20 04:07:35.707: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
08-20 04:07:35.827: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
```

Everytime when I click on the empty space, this error message will appear ;

```
08-20 04:07:35.707: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
    08-20 04:07:35.827: WARN/WindowManager(587): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
```

Thank you so much for taking your time reading this! I appreciate it!!

-Dayne

Answer (score 2):

Does the listView has the attribute as described in the error message?

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" ...
```

?

Comment: Yes i have that in my xml.

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: no, you don't ;-)
should be android:id="@android:id/list" not android:id="@+id/ListView"

Comment: Alrite! I give it a try now! :D

Comment: Oh no it's not working. But instead of force close, no listview appear. :/

Comment: you need to check the log and read the log message, usually it says what the error is. or post the error msg here that you're getting.

Comment: Im having trouble with my eclipse now. Before that, I check my log console. There was no error. but everytime i click oon the blank space, a yellow/orange in color message appeared. Something like I press null.... :/

Comment: Alrite. Eclipse is back. I post the log on the question so that you can view it better.