# What does this error mean regarding the ID of my ListView?

Tags: android, listview

The error below occurs when I try to run my program. Can anyone tell me what it means?

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
>   content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Duplicate of [Listview error can't run; force close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518720/listview-error-cant-run-force-close)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's right there in plain English. I will copy and paste it: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Basically, in your XML file that describes your layout, you need to create a ListView with an ID defined as "@id/android:list". The Android API will automatically find this view and use it for your list activity.

This is incidentally explained in detail in the documentation for ListActivity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html